# Sorting Excel VBA Macro based on combination of number and dot (.)

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

I'm looking for sorting a sheet in excel using a macro based on following criteria. I'm giving a sample below. Can you please let me know an algorithm to sort accordingly.

The sorting should be done based on number order alongwith one or multiple '.'.

For example I have following set of values in unsorted order:
[image: Unsorted]

I then need a macro which should sort the sheet based on ID that should be sorted considering number along with 1 or multiple '.'. So if there is 1, 1.1.1, 1.1, 1.2 the sorted order should be 1, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.2.

So the above unsorted sheet should look like following after the sorted macro runs

[image: Sorted]

Comment: Why not just get your VBA code to get Excel to sort it in ascending sequence?

Comment: Only ascending can't work. As it need to be sorted based on number sequence as well as ".".

Comment: I see you have updated your requirements to have different data.  In that case, you will need to write some VBA.  Post what you have so far and we may be able to help you complete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to the problem. I've splitted the ID column and based on . Delimiter using formula and came up with ranking and then created a Macro to sort the sheet based on ranking alongwith ID

[Excel Sheet Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yojq8.jpg)

```
Public Sub SortWorksheet()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(WS_SiteRawData).Activate
    Range("A3:IR1000").Select
    Selection.sort Key1:=Range("N3"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("E3") _
        , Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:= _
        False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick for me:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SortThis()

Dim lonLastRow As Long
Dim rng As Range

With ActiveSheet
  lonLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(lonLastRow, 2))
  rng.Sort Key1:=.Cells(2, 2)
End With

End Sub
```

Make sure to replace 'Activesheet' with a direct reference to the sheet you need (either by number, or bij name).

Comment: This does not work. Please look into updated requirement

Comment: it DOES work.. For  your updates requirements, you only need to adjust the range 'rng' and the Key1 according you your needs...